# API field configuring

Tags: sql, database, api, datetime

I see timestamp variable in api getting converted to 2 hours ahead and stored what time zone it is?

I want to know what timezone configuration is set to store how to set it for cet time

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain you how i do it for PsotgreSQL Here is an example that should help. If you have a timestamp with a timezone, you can convert that timestamp into any other timezone. If you haven't got a base timezone it won't be converted correctly.

```
SELECT now(),
   now()::timestamp,
   now() AT TIME ZONE 'CST',
   now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CST'
```

Output:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------
now      | 2018-09-15 17:01:36.399357+03
now      | 2018-09-15 17:01:36.399357
timezone | 2018-09-15 08:01:36.399357
timezone | 2018-09-16 02:01:36.399357+03
```